# Jquery mobile (or other js framework) and customizing buttons

Tags: themes, jquery-mobile, cordova

I am using jQuery mobile for developing by Phonegap.

Advantages:

- I like easy functionality (i.e. page navigation via hashes, auto pop-ups for loading.. etc)

Problem:

- I want to use my own images for buttons, toolbars, etc.. which will be dynamically generated in system, so prepared static .css is not option.
- so result is, that I want still have jQuery mobile functionality but disable styles for chosen widgets and use my own images

Comment: Could you dynamically generate the CSS as well?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I understand the problem. If you generate toolbars and buttons, why can you not assign the appropriate classes / IDs to them at run-time, and style accordingly in your static CSS file?

If everything *has* to be truly dynamic, simply generate the CSS overrides as well.

Comment: I.e. buttons are the most problematic:
- rounded corners means too much overriding styles
- catching onclick/hover events to add my own classes. Because jquery mobile(JM) dynamicaly adds his classes: i.e. onclick event adds JM own style which should override my style added before

For now I have made my own simulation of buttons.
Into Header and Footer I put own div element, which covers all their space, so this is solved too.

Better solution I didnt' find out.